# How can a ruby module enforce conditions on classes in which it is included?

Tags: ruby, module, metaprogramming

How can I write a ruby module that imposes some conditions on classes in which it is included, which must be met the end of currently opened class definition?

To be concrete, suppose the condition is "a class variable `@@foo` should be defined to be >0 "

I'd like to write a module that looks something like this:

```
module NeedPositiveFoo
  module ClassMethods
    def validate_positive_foo
      raise unless defined?(@@foo) && @@foo > 0
    end
  end

  def included(other)
    other.extend(ClassMethods)
  end
end
```

Then this class definition would be valid:

```
class ValidClass
  include NeedPositiveFoo
  @@foo = 3
end
```

But these class definitions would raise after their closing `end`'s:

```
class InvalidClass1
  include NeedPositiveFoo
  # @@foo is not defined
end

class InvalidClass2
  include NeedPositiveFoo
  @@foo = -2
end
```

Comment: There is no such thing as "the end of the class definition". A class body can be always opened later at any point. Or if you mean the syntax level, then you can use TracePoint.

Comment: @sawa this is not true. There is such thing as “the end of currently opened class definition,” applicable from inside `included` callback.

Comment: @mudasobwa What you are referring to is the syntax level. You are right about it, but I meant a different thing.

Comment: Yes, I meant "the end of currently opened class definition" as @mudasobwa inferred.  Will clarify the question phrasing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While the answer by Uri Agassi perfectly works when you are allowed to put includes in the very end of class definition, the code below will work despite where `include` was placed.

```
def included(other)
  TracePoint.new(:end) do |tp|
    if tp.self == other
      tp.disable
      raise unless defined?(other.class_variable_get(:@@foo)) # checks
    end
  end.enable
  other.extend(ClassMethods)
end
```

[`TracePoint` documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/TracePoint.html).

Comment: This is perhaps the only way to go with the OP's question. Although, the question is an XY-question.

Comment: @sawa Yes. At least, I could not find any working solution save for that.

Answer (score 4):

You can't hook the end of a class definition, because there isn't one - a class can be declared in different files, at different times, and in different libraries even.

What you can do, is check the condition *when the module is included*, and declare the inclusion at the end of your definition:

```
module NeedPositiveFoo
  def included(other)
    raise unless defined?(@@foo) && @@foo > 0
  end
end

class ValidClass
  @@foo = 3
  include NeedPositiveFoo
end

class InvalidClass1
  # @@foo is not defined
  include NeedPositiveFoo
end

class InvalidClass2
  @@foo = -2
  include NeedPositiveFoo
end

class InvalidClass3
  include NeedPositiveFoo

  @@foo = 4 # declared after inclusion - not a valid state...
end
```

Answer (score 2):

When asking questions like this, it is often useful to see how the Ruby core library does it. There are two well-known mixins in the Ruby core library which place certain conditions on the classes they are being mixed into:

- `Enumerable` requires that the class have an `each` method that can be called with zero arguments and takes a block, to which it `yield`s all the elements of the collection successively.
- `Comparable` requires that the class have a `<=>` method that can be called with a single argument and responds with either `-1`, `0`, or `1`, depending on whether the argument is considered to be greater than, equal, or less than the receiver.

In both of these cases, the requirements are simply stated in the documentation, not in code. It is up to the class author to make sure they are met.

In fact, in the `Enumerable` case, the requirements are not really stated *at all*, it is just assumed that any competent Ruby programmer knows them.

I would follow this style set out by the authors of the core library, since it is what Rubyists are used to.