# Rals 5.2 - how to set conditions on included for a module?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, module, rake, mixins

I have (I think) the reverse of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35694148/how-can-a-ruby-module-enforce-conditions-on-classes-in-which-it-is-included).

I have a module (ActiveConcern) that is normally included in some ActiveRecord models:

```
module IntegrityScoring
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    before_save :calculate_score, if: :has_changes_to_save?
  end

  def calculate_score
    # do some work
  end
end
```

Now I am writing a rake task that needs to call this calculate_score:

```
  task seed_weights: :environment do    
    include IntegrityScoring # * this line throws an error *

    Contact.all.each do |contact|
      contact.score = contact.calculate_score
      contact.save
    end
  end
```

The error thrown is:

```
undefined method `before_save' for Object:Class
```

In the context of the rake task, the `before_save` callback does not make sense (and in fact throws the error as that method does not exist here, since it's not an ActiveRecord model, just a PORO).

Obviously I could remove the `included` code from the module and add the `before_save` callback to every class that includes the module.

But I am hoping an easier solution would be to add a condition to the `included` so that before_save is only added to ActiveRecord models. Is that even possible...something like:

```
  included 'only if including class is type of ActiveRecord' do
    before_save :calculate_score, if: :has_changes_to_save?
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling calculate_score in the context of contact the include of IntegretyScoring is not needed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should be able to skip callbacks with

```rb
Contact.skip_callback(:save, :before, : calculate_score, raise: false))
```

Comment: Thanks but I don't want the Contact class itself to skip the callback. I want the Rake task to skip it. The problem is that when the rake task hits the 'included' line Rails crashes with the error that 'before_save' is not present on Object::Class - since obviously a Rake task is just a PORO and not an ActiveRecord class.

Comment: Ah, ok I misunderstood that part. But i see you are calling contact.calculate_score why do you need to include IntegrityScoring? That does not make any sense as far as I can see. You are not calling calculate_score in the context of the rake task.

Comment: Omg, 5pm on a Friday, I am so stupid. Please add that as the answer!

Comment: Sometimes a fresh pair of eyes help ;).